# detect if the current browser supports Unity 3D webplayer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a script that will detect if the current browser supports Unity3D's WebPlayer?

I've tried using progress.pluginStatus to detect the state "unsupported" but it never returns anything, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty soon, you can just use: `function supportsUnity() { return false; }` :)

Comment: soon? as in when? @Alexander O'Mara any solutions for now

Comment: Browsers are dropping NPAPI plugins entirely, some already have, and AFAIK Unity still relies on that API. https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/28/web-publishing-following-chrome-npapi-deprecation/

Answer (score 1):

Unity WebPlayer depends on NPAPI to run on Web Browsers. Chrome has removed NPAPI few years ago.

Firefox will [remove](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/) NPAPI by the end of 2016. This will decrease your audience by more than 70 percent.

To make it worse, WebPlayer  is now removed from Unity 5.4 and above.

Use [WebGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html). Unity supports build for WebGL and it runs on most used Browsers.

Now, to answer your question, there is no API to detect if NPAPI is enabled or not. The trick to do this is to check the version of the Web Browser. This you can use to determine if that version of browser supports NPAPI  or not.

So, you have to do a reserach yourself and find out which web broswer version for each  web browser disabled NPAPI.